# Leer y escribir fichero binario java

Tags: java, eclipse, objeto, filereader

intento que lea un archivo.txt que he creado escribiendo en binario con otro codigo.
No comprendo por que me da error y no lo lee.

este es el start

```
       DatosUsuario login = new DatosUsuario();

    // Creamos un objeto de tipo fila para asignarle un archivo
    File file = new File("login.txt");
    
    try {
        // Para poder leer utilizaremos un FileInputStream pasandole
        // como referencia el archivo de tipo File.
        FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(file);
        
        // Declaramos una variable objeto del tipo ObjectInputStream
        ObjectInputStream read;
        
        // Creamos un bucle para leer la información
        // Mientras haya bytes en el archivo.
        while(fileIS.available()>0) {
            read = new ObjectInputStream(fileIS);
            
            // En una variable objeto de tipo Persona almacenaremos
            // el objeto leido de tipo Object convertido en un objeto
            // de tipo persona
            DatosUsuario loginRead = (DatosUsuario) read.readObject();
            
             // Imprimimos el objeto leido en consola
            System.out.println(loginRead);
            
        }
        
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

esta es la clase

```
public class DatosUsuario {


private String usuario;
private String contrasenna;


public String getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}
public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}
public String getContrasenna() {
    return contrasenna;
}
public void setContrasenna(String contrasenna) {
    this.contrasenna = contrasenna;
}


    
}
```

alomejor hay una manera mejor de hacerlo sin usar clases, lo unico que quiero es poder leer ese archivo, use clases por si era mas organizado.
Este es el error que me ha dado

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast 
to class ACT5.DatosUsuario (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; 
ACT5.DatosUsuario is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at ACT5.Start.main(Start.java:36)
```

La linea 36 del start pone esto:

```
DatosUsuario loginRead = (DatosUsuario) read.readObject();
```

Comment: Suena a que lo que estás guardando no puede ser parseado de forma trivial a una instancia de la clase que indicas (hizo un readObject y le pareció que era un string común y corriente). Cómo generaste el archivo? (o qué contiene?)

Comment: Contiene 2 palabras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo resolvi usando este codigo que aprendi viendo varios tutoriales y mi profe me respondio con un ejemplo. La clase `DatosUsuarios` la cambie por `persona`.

la clase para escribir

```
 Persona persona = new Persona ();
     
    persona.setUsuario("fran");
    persona.setContrasenna("1234");

    File archivo = new File("escritura.txt");
     
    try {
       
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(archivo);
         
        ObjectOutputStream escribir = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
         
        escribir.writeObject(persona);
         
        escribir.close();
        fos.close();
         
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error escribiendo. "
                + e.getMessage());   
    }
```

la clase para leer

```
        File archivo = new File("escritura.txt");
        try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(archivo);
         
        ObjectInputStream leer;
         
        while(fis.available()>0){
            leer= new ObjectInputStream(fis);
             
            Persona personaLeida= (Persona) leer.readObject();
             
            System.out.println(personaLeida);   
        }
         
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error leyendo archivo. "
                + e.getMessage());   
    }
```

la clase persona

```
    import java.io.*;

    public class Persona implements Serializable {

    private String usuario;
    private String contrasenna;
    
    
    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }
    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }
    public String getContrasenna() {
        return contrasenna;
    }
    public void setContrasenna(String contrasenna) {
        this.contrasenna = contrasenna;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Persona [usuario=" + usuario + ", contrasenna=" + contrasenna + "]";
    }
```

Comment: Como vez, te faltaba un toString para poder plasmar la clase _como un string_. Luego, entender qué es lo que se plasma en el archivo y cómo hace Java para leerlo de vuelta en una instancia de la clase. La programación no es magia :)

Comment: Estamos empezando con estas cosas, el profe me dijo que ya mas adelante entenderemos el codigo. Se que la programacion no es magia pero poco a poco entendere

Answer (score 1):

El error indica un problema de conversión:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> java.lang.String cannot be cast  to class ACT5.DatosUsuario

El método `readObject()` de [ObjectInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) devuelve un valor de tipo `String`, no puede ser convertido directamente a `DatosUsuario`, por lo tanto simplemente obtén este valor como `String` e imprimelo.

```
//DatosUsuario loginRead = (DatosUsuario) read.readObject(); ///INCORRECTO
String loginRead = (String) read.readObject(); //CORRECTO

// Imprimimos el objeto leido en consola
System.out.println(loginRead);
```

---

Comentas que ahora tienes el error:

> StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header

Recuerda que si lees con `readObject()` debes escribir con `writeObject()`, me parece que tu archivo `Login.txt` no contiene la información para poder deserializar y construir un objeto `DatosUsuario`, revisa este ejemplo:

```
public class ObjectInputStreamExample {

public static class Person implements Serializable {
    public String name = null;
    public int    age  =   0;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream =
        new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Persona.txt"));

    Person person = new Person();
    person.name = "Jorgesys Jenkov";
    person.age  = 31;

    //Escribe objeto
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(person);
    objectOutputStream.close();


    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream =
        new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Persona.txt"));
    //Lee objeto
    Person personRead = (Person) objectInputStream.readObject();

    objectInputStream.close();

    System.out.println(personRead.name);
    System.out.println(personRead.age);
}
```

Comment: Ahora me da error en el `read = new ObjectINputStream(fileIS);` y me salta el error de `invalid stream header`

Comment: El error que comentas es otro diferente, recuerda que si lees con readObject () debe escribir con writeObject ()

Comment: lo de implements `Serializable` es algo que no he dado y no llego a comprender del todo pero si que llega a funcionar muchas gracias^^. Tambien deje el codigo que es tal cual lo entiendo bien y queria mi profe